# Question about the use of DISTINCT when using subqueries

Tags: sql, subquery

So the problem given: Obtain the cast list for the film 'Alien'.

My initial code was:

```
select name
from actor
join casting
on actor.id=actorid where actorid in (
select actorid from casting join movie on movieid=id where title='alien')
```

I got an error because each actor was listed multiple times, I resolved it by selecting DISTINCT name, but I kind of don't understand why there was a multiple listing of actors? The subquery gives only actorids' that where listed in casting table with movieid corresponding to title 'Alien'. So there is only one distinct actorid from this query.

Comment: share tables shample data

Comment: *why there was a multiple listing of actors?* because each actor has multiple rows in the table casting.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting multiple rows for each actor because each actor is in multiple movies (presumably).  You are filtering by the *actor*, but there are already multiple rows.

So, you don't need the outer `join`:

```
select a.name
from actor a
where a.id in (select c.actorid
               from casting c join
                    movie m
                    on c.movieid = m.id 
               where m.title = 'alien'
              );
```

Voila!  No duplicates and no `select distinct`.

More importantly:

- Qualify *all* column references, particularly in a query that references multiple tables.
- Use table aliases so the query is simpler to write and to read.